# How to catch Bluetooth outgoing data on Android phone?

Tags: android, audio, networking, bluetooth

I want to capture outgoing data which is sending via bluetooth (ex: when I use bluetooth earphone, outgoing data will be all sound from my phone, I want to capture these sound). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[There's an app for that](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android_rsap.logger&hl=en)

Do you want to do this programatically?

The data will not be all sound though, It will contain lot of overhead as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I need some solution which I dont have to root my phone

Comment: @TrungTran There is no solution like that. Its not possible to get access to that data without root.